# all components became smaller on mobile device after change the architecture to isomorphic

Tags: material-ui

I have change my app architecture from client rendering to isomorphic. After that, I found that all components became much smaller on mobile device while behaving normal on PC. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please have a look at the sections [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I ran into the same thing and have a possible lead on it - it may have to do with using pixels versus using rem. I think if you switch out to using rem-based sizing for things in the whole app, it may account for things accordingly. This does not answer the question (which is why I'm not posting an answer) because I haven't tested the theory yet. But may be of help.